# Trigger that changes button content several times

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I have a button that is used for sorting things. I can set easily it's content change in code-behind but it's a dirty approach. I know there are triggers that can do this task, but all information I've found about them is aimed to single behavior (color change while mouse is over, etc).

I need three different contents for my button: "ABC", "ZYX" and "Default".

I've done this in code-behind this way:

```
int SortState = 0;
     private void sortButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SortState ++;
        if (SortState == 3)
        {
            SortState = 0;
        }
         switch (SortState )
         {
             case 0:
                     {
                         sortButton.Content = "ABC";
                          break;
                     }
             case 1:
                     {
                         sortButton.Content = "ZYX";
                         break;
                     }
             case 2:
                     {
                         sortButton.Content = "Default";
                         break;
                     }
         }

    }
```

Could someone give me a hint to how to do the same in XAML?

Comment: I think, that you won't get anything 'less dirty' in XAML ;-). I think it could be done somehow with `EventTrigger` and `Storyboard`, but don't know exactly how ;-).

Comment: Or alternatively EventTrigger and Multibinding. Alternative solution incoming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've tried.

```
<Style.Triggers>       
    <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="0">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Default" />
    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="XYZ" />
    </Trigger>

    <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="2">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="ABC" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

but still you have to change Tag value somehow. Maybe with EventTrigger, but I don't know how.

Comment: WTF. Thank you very much for the effort, but I thought it would be like.. 2 lines of code as usually in XAML. If I'm sincere to you I think I will maintain the code-behind. Anyway my application is already far away from the pure MVVM style!

Comment: :-) I don't think so, that it can be done so easily in XAML. BTW. I've modified my example to simpler version ;-).
With that XAML you could add one line in code-behind, like: btn.Tag = (((int)btn.Tag) + 1) % 3);

Comment: Great! I think as the button action will be bound to a Command I can also bind the Tag to the parameter that dictates the Command behavior. And change the Tag value in each command execution. What do you think?

Comment: Yeap, it could be like that or as I've written: add to Click event: btn.Tag = ((int)btn.Tag) + 1) % 3;

Comment: Btw. to MVVM pattern I recommend Caliburn.Micro, easy and nice framework ;-).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using MVVM:

Create a property in your ViewModel that stores your `SortState`

```
    public int SortState
    {
        get { return _sortState; }
        set
        {
            _sortState = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SortState");
        }
    }
```

Create a command in your ViewModel to handle button clicks:

```
    public ICommand SortStateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sortStateCommand == null)
                _sortStateCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
                    {
                        SortState++;
                        if (SortState == 3)
                            SortState = 0;
                    });
            return _sortStateCommand;
        }
    }
```

Create a Converter to convert your `SortState` into Text:

```
public class SortStateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = (int) value;
        var returnVal = string.Empty;
        switch (val)
        {
            case 0:
                returnVal = "ABC";
                break;
            case 1:
                returnVal = "ZYX";
                break;
            case 2:
                returnVal = "Default";
                break;
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Hook it all together in your View:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication1:SortStateConverter x:Key="SortConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Content="{Binding SortState, Converter={StaticResource SortConverter}}"
        Command="{Binding SortStateCommand}">
</Button>
```

The RelayCommand implementation is from MVVMLight.